# SQL query. Joining column with itself, looks like should work but missing pairs

Tags: sql

I've simplified the database to make it easier. Here's the diagram:

[image]

We have products. Products belong to categories and have manufacturers.

What I need is,  **for every pair of categories, to find the count of manufacturers that have manufactured products of both categories.**

So the result set needs to look like this (this is not actual data):

[image]

**This is what I've tried so far:**

```
SELECT phC1.category_id as Cat1 , PhC2.category_id as Cat2, COUNT(PhM.manufacturer_id)
FROM
product_has_category phC1, product_has_category phC2, product_has_manufacturer PhM
WHERE
PhM.product_id = phC1.product_id AND PhM.product_id=PhC2.product_id  AND PhC1.category_id < phC2.category_id 
group by PhC1.category_id, PhC2.category_id
order by PhC1.category_id, PhC2.category_id
```

---

This looks to me like it should be right, but I'm getting less results than I should be. I'm missing some Category pairs. Am I approaching this wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Please edit the question and post the `CREATE TABLE` statements of the tables, some `INSERT INTO` providing sample data and the result you expect with that sample data (as text please!). Maybe also mention the DBMS you're using in the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some assumptions, which may be wrong.

1. I assumed, that there's a `Categories` table - as this makes things
   easier.
2. I assumed, that a product can have multiple (or no) categories.
3. I assumed, that a category can be assigned to multiple (or no) products.
4. For manufacturers, I took the same assumptions, as for categories.

This is what I came up with:

```
SELECT c1.Category_id AS Cat1,
       c2.Category_id AS Cat2,
       COUNT( DISTINCT
         CASE
           WHEN c1m.Manufacturer_id = c2m.Manufacturer_id
           THEN c1m.Manufacturer_id
         END
       ) AS pCount
  FROM Category AS c1
 INNER JOIN Category AS c2
    ON c1.Category_id < c2.Category_id
  LEFT JOIN ProductHasCategory c1p
    ON c1p.Category_id = c1.Category_id
  LEFT JOIN ProductHasCategory c2p
    ON c2p.Category_id = c2.Category_id
  LEFT JOIN ProductHasManufacturer c1m
    ON c1m.Product_id = c1p.Product_id
  LEFT JOIN ProductHasManufacturer c2m
    ON c2m.Product_id = c2p.Product_id
 GROUP BY c1.Category_id, c2.Category_id
 ORDER BY 1, 2
```

This is a fiddle for it, using MS SQL Server:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/461cc/1